# D3.JS Delete points with reindexing both points and segments arrays

Tags: arrays, d3.js, point, splice, reindex

Let's say I have an arbitrary points array, i.e.

```
var points = [

    //e: terminals
    //a: arm
    //s: support

    {x: 32, y: 256, t: "e"},
    {x: 250, y: 256, t: "a"},
    {x: 260, y: 256, t: "s"},
    {x: 320, y: 256, t: "a"},
    {x: 330, y: 256, t: "s"},
    {x: 128, y: 256, t: "a"},
    {x: 138, y: 256, t: "s"},
    {x: 480, y: 256, t: "e"}

];
```

And another one, called segments, which defines how these points set into one path:

```
var segments = [

    {start: 0, support: null, end: 5},
    {start: 5, support: 6, end: 1},
    {start: 1, support: 2, end: 3},
    {start: 3, support: 4, end: 7}

];
```

The arm point (t: "a") have always its following t: "s" support one.

By double-clicking on the arm point (magenta) the code has to delete it as well as its support point (cyan) and reindex points and segments array.

For example, if you want to delete {x: 128, y: 256, t: "a"} and its pair {x: 138, y: 256, t: "s"}, the reindexed arrays have to be like this:

var points = [

```
{x: 32, y: 256, t: "e"},
{x: 250, y: 256, t: "a"},
{x: 260, y: 256, t: "s"},
{x: 320, y: 256, t: "a"},
{x: 330, y: 256, t: "s"},
{x: 480, y: 256, t: "e"}
```

];

var segments = [

```
{start: 0, support: null, end: 1},
{start: 1, support: 2, end: 3},
{start: 3, support: 5, end: 5}
```

];

And I could find an efficient way to do this reindexing.
The code is attached.

```js
var points = [
    
    //e: terminals
    //a: arm
    //s: support
    
    {x: 32, y: 256, t: "e"},
    {x: 250, y: 256, t: "a"},
    {x: 260, y: 256, t: "s"},
    {x: 320, y: 256, t: "a"},
    {x: 330, y: 256, t: "s"},
    {x: 128, y: 256, t: "a"},
    {x: 138, y: 256, t: "s"},
    {x: 480, y: 256, t: "e"}
    
    //the fist and last points are always end ones
    
];
    
var segments = [
    
    {start: 0, support: null, end: 5},
    {start: 5, support: 6, end: 1},
    {start: 1, support: 2, end: 3},
    {start: 3, support: 4, end: 7}

];

var svg = d3.select("#container");

var path = svg.append("path")
           .attr("d", generatePath())
           .attr("stroke", "#000000")
           .attr("stroke-width", 2);
    
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
           .data(getAllPoints())
           .enter()
           .append("circle")
           .attr("class", "node")
           .attr("cx", function(d_) { return d_.x; })
           .attr("cy", function(d_) { return d_.y; })
           .attr("r", 4)
           .attr("fill", function(d_){ 
               
               if(d_.t == "e") { return "#FF0000"; }
               else if(d_.t == "s") { return "#00FFFF"; }
               return "#FF00FF";
                                     
           })
           .on("dblclick", function(d_){
               
               if(d_.t == "a"){
                   
                   console.log("have to delete this point and its support")
                   console.log("and reindex points and segments array")
                    
                   //if there is only one pair of a/s points
                   //the solution is straight forward
                   //while first and last points are always end ones
                   
                   if(segments.length == 2){
       
                       points.splice(d_.id, 2);
                       points.forEach(function(p_, i_){ p_.id = i_; });
                       newSegments = [{start: 0, support: null, end: 1}];
                       
                   }else{
                       
                        //could find effective solution here
                        //has to work but it doesn't
                       
                        //segments.forEach(function(segment_){
                        //
                        //  if(segment_.end != d_.id){
                        //
                        //      var start = segment_.start,
                        //          support = segment_.support,
                        //          end = segment_.end;
                        //
                        //      if(start > d_.id - 2) { start -= 2; }
                        //      if(support > d_.id - 2 && support != null) { support -= 2; }
                        //      if(end > d_.id - 2) { end -= 2; }
                        //
                        //      newSegments.push({start: start, support: support, end: end})
                        //
                        //  }
                        //
                        //  points.splice(d_.id, 2);
                        //  points.forEach(function(p_, i_){ p_.id = i_; });
                        //  segments = newSegments;
    
                   }
               }
               
           })

function generatePath(){
    
    var out = "";

    segments.forEach(function(segment_, i_){
        
        if(i_ == 0) { 
            
            //skip support point
            out += "M" + points[segment_.start].x + " " + points[segment_.start].y;
            out += " L" + points[segment_.end].x + " " + points[segment_.end].y;
        
        }else{
            
            out += " L" + points[segment_.start].x + " " + points[segment_.start].y;
            out += " L" + points[segment_.support].x + " " + points[segment_.support].y;
            out += " L" + points[segment_.end].x + " " + points[segment_.end].y;
            
        }

    })

    return out;
    
}
    
function getAllPoints(){
    
    var out = [];

    points.forEach(function(point_, i_){ out.push(point_); out[out.length - 1].id = i_; });

    return out;
    
}
```

```css
 body { margin: 0; }
        #container { 
            
            position: absolute; 
            left: 0; top: 0; 
            width: 512px; 
            height: 512px; 
            background-color: darkgray;
        
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>D3.JS: Points chain</title>
  
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    
    
</head>
<body>

<svg id="container" width="512" height="512"></svg>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I've found the solution by myself.

```js
var points = [
    
    //e: terminals
    //a: arm
    //s: support
    
    {x: 32, y: 256, t: "e"},
    {x: 250, y: 256, t: "a"},
    {x: 260, y: 256, t: "s"},
    {x: 320, y: 256, t: "a"},
    {x: 330, y: 256, t: "s"},
    {x: 128, y: 256, t: "a"},
    {x: 138, y: 256, t: "s"},
    {x: 480, y: 256, t: "e"}
    
    //the fist and last points are always end ones
    
];
    
var segments = [
    
    {start: 0, support: null, end: 5},
    {start: 5, support: 6, end: 1},
    {start: 1, support: 2, end: 3},
    {start: 3, support: 4, end: 7}

];


var svg = d3.select("#container");    
    
draw();


function draw(){
    
    svg.selectAll("path").remove();
    svg.selectAll("circle").remove();
    
    var path = svg.append("path")
           .attr("d", generatePath())
           .attr("stroke", "#000000")
           .attr("stroke-width", 2);
    
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
           .data(getAllPoints())
           .enter()
           .append("circle")
           .attr("class", "node")
           .attr("cx", function(d_) { return d_.x; })
           .attr("cy", function(d_) { return d_.y; })
           .attr("r", 4)
           .attr("fill", function(d_){ 
               
               if(d_.t == "e") { return "#FF0000"; }
               else if(d_.t == "s") { return "#00FFFF"; }
               return "#FF00FF";
                                     
           })
           .on("dblclick", function(d_){
               
               if(d_.t == "a"){
                   
                   if(segments.length == 2){
       
                       points.splice(d_.id, 2);
                       points.forEach(function(p_, i_){ p_.id = i_; });
                       segments = [{start: 0, support: null, end: 1}];
                       
                   }else{
                        
                        var newsegs = [];
                       
                        for(var i = 0; i < segments.length; i++){
                          
                          if(segments[i].end == d_.id){
                              
                              if(i < segments.length - 2){
                                  
                                  newsegs.push({

                                      start: segments[i].start,
                                      support: segments[i].support,
                                      end: segments[i + 1].end


                                  });

                                  newsegs.push({

                                      start: segments[i + 2].start,
                                      support: segments[i + 2].support,
                                      end: segments[i + 2].end


                                  });

                                  i += 2; continue;
                                  
                              }else{
                                                                    
                                  newsegs.push({

                                      start: segments[i].start,
                                      support: segments[i].support,
                                      end: segments[i + 1].end

                                  });
                                  
                                  i++; continue;
        
                              }
                              
                          }else{
                              
                              newsegs.push(segments[i]);
                              
                          }
                          
                      }
                       
                      newsegs.forEach(function(segment_){
                          
                          if(segment_.start >= d_.id) { segment_.start -= 2; }
                          if(segment_.support >= d_.id) { segment_.support -= 2; }
                          if(segment_.end >= d_.id) { segment_.end -= 2; }
                          
                      })
                       
                        segments = newsegs;
                        points.splice(d_.id, 2);
                        points.forEach(function(p_, i_){ p_.id = i_; });

                   }
                   
                   console.log(points);
                   console.log(segments);
                   draw();
               }
               
           })

    
}
function generatePath(){
    
    var out = "";

    segments.forEach(function(segment_, i_){
        
        if(i_ == 0) { 
            
            //skip support point
            out += "M" + points[segment_.start].x + " " + points[segment_.start].y;
            out += " L" + points[segment_.end].x + " " + points[segment_.end].y;
        
        }else{
            
            out += " L" + points[segment_.start].x + " " + points[segment_.start].y;
            //out += " L" + points[segment_.support].x + " " + points[segment_.support].y;
            out += " L" + points[segment_.end].x + " " + points[segment_.end].y;
            
        }

    })

    return out;
    
}
    
function getAllPoints(){
    
    var out = [];

    points.forEach(function(point_, i_){ out.push(point_); out[out.length - 1].id = i_; });

    return out;
    
}
```

```css
    body { margin: 0; }
        #container { 
            
            position: absolute; 
            left: 0; top: 0; 
            width: 512px; 
            height: 512px; 
            background-color: darkgray;
        
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>D3.JS: Points chain</title>
  
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />

    
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    
    
</head>
<body>

<svg id="container" width="512" height="512"></svg>

</body>
</html>
```